# Trigger re-render on dropdown select menu change - using React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to get this to rerender without using setInterval just by using componentWillUpdate. I have had a read at React lifecycles.
I am fairly confident I am missing something around event firing / dom rendering.

```
var MainDiv = React.createClass({
  loadModuleFromServer: function(value) {

    var iri = 'http://someurl';
    value = this.state.value;

    $.ajax({
      url: iri + value,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data['@key']});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: [], windowWidth: window.innerWidth, value: "000001"};
  },
  handleResize: function(e) {
    this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth});
  },
  handleChange: function() {
  this.setState({value: selectMenu.value});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadModuleFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadModuleFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },
render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="MainDiv">
      <div className="header">
      <h1><img src={'http://someurl?w=' + this.state.windowWidth} alt="header"/>
      </h1></div>
        <HeroData data={this.state.data} width={this.state.windowWidth}/>
      <select id="selectMenu" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.value}>
      <option value="000001">English</option>
      <option value="000002">French</option>
      </select>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <MainDiv pollInterval={1000}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Output is:

```
<div class="MainDiv" data-reactid=".0">
    <div class="header" data-reactid=".0.0">
        <h1 data-reactid=".0.0.0"><img src="http://someheader?w=1280" alt="header" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0"></h1></div>
    <div class="mainModule" data-reactid=".0.1"><img src="https://someurl?w=1280&fmt=jpg" alt="Alt text" data-reactid=".0.1.0">
        <h2 data-reactid=".0.1.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.1.0">Blurb1</span></h2>
        <h3 data-reactid=".0.1.2"><span data-reactid=".0.1.2.0">Blurb2.</span></h3>
        <h4 data-reactid=".0.1.3"><span data-reactid=".0.1.3.0">Blurb3</span></h4><a href="http://someurl" class="CTA" data-reactid=".0.1.4">Click here</a></div>
    <select id="selectMenu" data-reactid=".0.2">
        <option value="000001" data-reactid=".0.2.0">English</option>
        <option value="000002" data-reactid=".0.2.1">French</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have omitted the part where I map the data retrieved from server to get this content.

Many Thanks.

Edit: I have followed Kishore Barik's advice. Event was fired. But it was still not triggering a rerender. It was not listening to the event change. So I change the componentDidMount to:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadModuleFromServer();
    selectMenu.addEventListener('change',this.loadModuleFromServer);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },
```

and handleChange to:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
this.setState({value: selectMenu.value});
},
```

It is re-rendering but one change behind ie. as per selection, displaying English content when French is selected and French when English is selected.
Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: What do you get for output?

Comment: this is happening because both event are firing simultaneously,while *loadModuleFromServer* is called at that time it holds the old state. wait, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your **handleChange** method being called or not putting a console.log
 If it's being called I can see the one error i.e. inside **handleChange** you are taking value from selectMenu.value where **selectMenu** is undefined.
For that you can always retrieve value as old javascript/jquery way

```
document.getElementById('selectMenu').value();
```

or `$('#selectMenu').val()`

or else you can use the **react way**. for that
 1. you have to give a reference to your select

```
<select id="selectMenu" ref="mySelect" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.value}>
```

2. Then you have to get the value from the select as per your react version it may be

   this.refs.mySelect.value;

or

```
this.refs.mySelect.getDOMNode().value;
```

or

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mySelect).value;
```

please go through documentation or comment if you have any query

> **Edit as per new changes to question**

no need to add event listener of select change from **componentDidMount**
just do

```
handleChange: function() {
  this.loadModuleFromServer(selectMenu.value);
},
```

and remove the line  **value = this.state.value;** inside **loadModuleFromServer** function body.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the event to your function or set state directly

```
    <select onChange={event => this.setState({value:event.target.value})}>
```